# How to solve the simple Ito (stochastic) integral over Brownian motion via the Ito formula?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

**Question:**

Let $X(t)=\int_0^t W(s)dW(s)$ where $W(t)$ is the Brownian motion (Wiener process). What function $f(X(t))$ of $X(t)$ can be used with the Itô formula to get the explicit result $X(t)=\frac{1}{2} W(t)^2 - \frac{1}{2}t$?

**Details (if context needed):**

The textbook introduction of [Itô's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma) is preceded/motivated by the Itô (stochastic) integral of the type $\int X(s)dW(s)$, where $X(t)$ is an Itô-integrable stochastic process. It is then shown, as a simple initial example, that $\int_0^tW(s)dW(s)=\frac{1}{2} W(t)^2 - \frac{1}{2}t$, by simply writing the integral as the limit of the sum of sub-intervals and rearranging as such:

$$
\int_0^tW(s)dW(s) \\ 
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} W \left ( \frac{t}{n}i \right ) \left ( W \left (  \frac{t}{n}i+1 \right )  - W \left (  \frac{t}{n}i \right )\right ) \right ) \\
= \frac{1}{2} W(t)^2 - \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  \left ( W \left (  \frac{t}{n}i+1 \right )  - W \left (  \frac{t}{n}i \right )\right ) \right )^2}_{=<W(t)>=t} \\
= \frac{1}{2} W(t)^2 - \frac{1}{2}t \\ 
$$

where $<W(t)>$ is the quadratic variation. [explicit calculations are [here chp19.2.2, p139](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/754/notes/lecture-19.pdf); also cf. Bingham & Kiesel (2014). Risk Neutral Valuation. Chp5.5, Eq(5.1)]. Then the Itô formula is introduced as a generalization.

Can the above result be shown via the Itô formula, and *not* via the limiting sum as was done above? If so, how?

For example, for the geometric Brownian motion with SDE $dX(t)=X(t)(\mu dt + \sigma dW(t))$ the function $f(X(t))=\log(X(t))$ is used with the Itô formula. Some terms cancel nicely out so that all integrals become easy to calculate and then we can solve for $X(t)$. Is something like this possible for the integral above?

Comment: Always a good idea to pick function $f$ assuming usual Riemann integral. In your case try $f(x) = x^2$

Comment: Note that in Ito's formula, under integral with $dW(s)$ you have $f'(W(s))$. So if you want to $"$compute$"$ something like $\int_0^t g(W(s))dW(s)$, you should try to use Ito's formula with $f$ such that $f'(x) = g(x)$. In your case $g(x) = x$, so you're looking for $f$ such that $f'(x) = x$. Can you try to proceed?

Comment: @Ilya: thanks! What do you mean by "assuming Riemann integral"? Applying Ito using $f=x^2$ and $dX_t=W_tdW_t$, I get: $f=f(x_0)+\int f'dX_t+ 1/2 \int f''<dX_t>=0+\int 2X_tW_tdW_t+1/2\int2 W_t^2dt$. The integrals are not solvable (?).

Comment: @DominikKutek: thanks! Even if I try $f=x^2/2$, as you suggest, this will only lead to the $2$ disappearing from the middle integral above and no cancellation in the second, but I wouldn't know how to proceed further.

Comment: But you use $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}$ with process $W$, not $X$, that is you write $f(W(t))$ with Ito's formula (that way you will generate term $X(t) = \int_0^t f'(W(s))dW(s)$ and that's the reason why we picked $f$ such that $f'(x) = x$)

Comment: @DominikKutek: oh, that's very smart!! So, not applying Ito formula on the process $X(t)$ itself (as the formula says), but choosing $f(\cdot)$ in such a way that applying Ito on $W(t)$ with $f(\cdot)$ it leads to an expression that contains $X(t)$ (and the rest of the terms are easy) for which we can then solve. Indeed this leads to the desired result. Would you mind posting it as an answer so I can mark it? Also, is it possible to find a function of $X(t)$ itself so that the Ito formula can be applied directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeking an explicit formula for $$X(t)= \int_0^t W(s)dW(s),$$ which is of the form $\int_0^t g(W(s))dW(s)$ for $g(x)=x$. You want to calculate it by Ito's Formula, which in the case of Wiener Process boils down to $$f(W(t)) = f(0) + \int_0^t f'(W(s))dW(s) + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(W(s))ds. $$
The only term which has integral with respect to Wiener Process (that is, $dW(s)$ term) is the middle one, hence we need $f$ such that $X(t) = \int_0^t f'(W(s))dW(s)$ for any $t$, so the "simpliest" candidate is to try to find $f$ such that $f'(x) = x$ (then $f'(W(s)) = W(s)$). We see that $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}$ works, which gives $$ \frac{W^2(t)}{2} = 0 + \int_0^t W(s)dW(s) + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t 1 ds = \int_0^t W(s)dW(s) + \frac{t}{2},$$ hence $$ X(t) = \int_0^t W(s)dW(s) = \frac{1}{2}\left( W^2(t) - t\right).$$

Comment: Thanks again, very neat trick! But I'll ask once more: is it possible to find a function of $X(t)$ (not of $W(t)$) so that the Ito formula can be applied to $X(t)$, similar to the GBM example I gave above? If not, why not?

Comment: It would be hard I think, because using Ito's formula with $X$, you get $f(X(t)) = f(0) + \int_0^t f'(X(s))W(s)dW(s) + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(X(s))W^2(s)ds$. To find (explicit) formula for $f(X(t))$, you need some cancelations, but it isn't obvious from the definition how $f'(X(s))W(s)$ is related to $f''(X(s))W^2(s)$. The reason why in the example of SDE with geometric BM it worked is that under integral you still have only $X(s)$ dependence, which is not the case above. But note that what I did in answer above is really simplier than solving SDE.